# Limitations of let rec in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm studying OCaml these days and came across this:

OCaml has limits on what it can put on the righthand side of a let rec. Like this one

```
let memo_rec f_norec =
let rec f = memoize (fun x -> f_norec f x) in
f;; 
Error: This kind of expression is not allowed as right-hand side of `let rec'
```

in which, the memoize is a function that take a function and turns it into a memorized version with Hashtable. It's apparent that OCaml has some restriction on the use of constructs at the right-hand side of 'let rec', but I don't really get it, could anyone explain a bit more on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The kind of expressions that are allowed to be bound by `let rec` are described in [section 8.1](https://ocaml.org/manual/letrecvalues.html) of the manual. Specifically, function applications involving the `let rec` defined names are not allowed.

A rough summary (taken from that very link):

> Informally, the class of accepted definitions consists of those definitions where the defined names occur only inside function bodies or as argument to a data constructor.

Answer (score 9):

You can use tying-the-knot techniques to define memoizing fixpoints. See for example those two equivalent definitions:

```
let fix_memo f =
  let rec g = {contents = fixpoint}
  and fixpoint x = f !g x in
  g := memoize !g;
  !g

let fix_memo f =
  let g = ref (fun _ -> assert false) in
  g := memoize (fun x -> f !g x);
  !g
```

Or using `lazy` as reminded by Alain:

```
let fix_memo f =
  let rec fix = lazy (memoize (fun x -> f (Lazy.force fix) x)) in
  Lazy.force fix
```